# Looking for BQ SQL builder from config file

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm developing a common function to compose Big Query SQL query from a JSON config file. The whole idea is to achieve reusable snippet of code by other SQL query, like where clause, formula, case..when. These are all maintained in the config file.

Question I have, 
Is there a best practice already of how the config is structured so it supports table joins, nested queries.
And is there library to compose Big Query compatible query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Firstly, it is not easy to have a general purpose "config file" to generate SQL, if there were such config, it must be written in SQL :) Secondly, you touched join/nest query, you may also want to add aggregation (GROUP BY) and sorting (ORDER BY) and maybe LIMIT. There is always effort trying to map SQL (or relational model) to other paradigm, one famous effort is named ORM. Some of them also has "config" (combined with code) to do almost everything mentioned above, you can take a look.

Comment: Could you use persistent UDFs to solve your problem instead? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_function_statement